# How to deselect UITableView cell when user click to button?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working on a project in which I have to select a particular cell. I can select a cell in my `UITableView`, but I want to deselect all cells when the user clicks on Button -RESET-< I mean button action> so I don't know how I can do it. I need help, please.

My code to select a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //changer la couleur de la cellule à la selection
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    if !Array( addObject.dictionnary.values)[indexPath.row] {
        addObject.dictionnary[Array( addObject.dictionnary.keys)[indexPath.row]] = true
    } else {
        addObject.dictionnary[Array( addObject.dictionnary.keys)[indexPath.row]] = false
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick code snippet that might lead you in the correct direction.

```
@IBAction func onResetButtonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
     if let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
          for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: in this line : class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {}

Comment: What is your stack trace from the crash? Did you previously have another method that the button was connected to in the storyboard? In which, you deleted the method the button was connected to? The outlet in the storyboard would be flagged with an exclamation mark.

Comment: sorry, my button was connected to another method, now I dont have an error but my row not deselect when a click to my button. i dont understand where I add  an exclamation mark exactly (sorry im  beginner in swift).

Comment: @s.satcha Do you have the source code anywhere that I could possibly make a commit and show you the fix? You don't have to put an exclamation mark anywhere. In the storyboard when there is a bad connection between an element and an IBAction or IBOutlet instead of having a filled in circle. There is an exclamation mark over the circle.

Comment: @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            for indexPath in selectedIndexPaths {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            }
        }

    }

Comment: @s.satcha I think there is just a issue of misunderstanding there. The UITableView has a selection mode for either None, Single, or Multiple selection. Then there is another option for selection style of a cell. You don't need to change the content view's color on selection and deselection. The color change is already handled for you.

Comment: I used this function but it's not deselected

Comment: @s.satcha it looks like in the code you provided that you were changing the background color of the content view of the cell that you selected? Maybe there is confusion of the cell being selected vs you having the content view's background color set?

Comment: i have imageView in my content's view and for my cell that is selected a use :        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 tableView.deselectRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this and found some docs from Apple at [Link to Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/handling_row_selection_in_a_table_view) but it showed to put the call at ViewWillAppear. Xcode didn't like it, so after more research, finally found that this is the place to put it

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

within the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```